# VFDB search output

Tags: pathogenicity

I want to check virulence factor of bacteria protein sequence by using Virulence Factor Database and it shows No hit in VFDB BLAST search output. Will someone please explain what is meant by it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is your question about why blast doesn't get a hit, or about why your protein isn't in VFDB? BLAST and VFDB both have documentation about how they work, can you try to investigate there?

Comment: if VFDB result show No Hit for a protein, so is it means it is non-virulent?